# How can I detect edges on an image of a document, and cut sections into seperate images?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, scikit-image, canny-operator

The task is to take an image of a document, and leverage straight lines surrounding different 'sections' in order to split up the image into different documents for further parsing.  Size of the different 'sections' is completely variable from page to page (we're dealing with several thousand pages).  Here is an image of what one of these images looks like:

Example of how the documents are laid out:

[image: Example Doc]

Image analysis/manipulation is completely new to me.  So far I've attempted to use Scikit-image edge detection algorithms to find the 'boxes', with hopes to use those 'coordinates' to cut the image.  However, the two algorithms I've tried (Canny, Hough) are picking up lines of text as 'edges' on high sensitivity, and not picking up the lines that I want on low sensitivity.  I could write something custom and low level to detect the boxes myself, but I have to assume this is a solved problem.

Is my approach headed in the right direction?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have some real input images as well? What you show is useful to illustrate the concept. but you really need to work with the real world inputs.

Comment: Added a real input image, although documents to be parsed come from a variety of different sources.  The format overall format is expected to always be similar, but line size, language, text formatting, etc. are prone to change.

Comment: That appears to be a computer generated image, rather than an image acquired by a scanner, or a camera. (Judging by how all the lines are perfectly horizontal/vertical) Is that what all the inputs will be like? If so, that definitely makes the task easier.

Comment: Lets assume so.  I believe that the image is an output of the pdftoppm program, in case that is helpful.

Comment: The top half of the page appears to be one *"article"* which is 4 columns wide and the bottom half appears to be two *"articles"* one of which is 3 columns wide and the other one column wide. Are you trying to detect *"articles"* or columns because "*articles"* are surrounded with a black line and columns are surrounded by white gaps.

Comment: We are trying to detect the 'articles' surrounded by the black lines, and not the different columns surrounded by white gaps.  The articles are split into up to 4 vertical columns and up to 4 rows, although sometimes the article is huge and covers the entire page or half page, as you see here.

Comment: @migsvult Since those lines are perfectly horizontal/vertical, something like horizontal/vertical projection could work to segment the articles. Use this approach to recursively segment the image, alternating between horizontal and vertical subdivision. You stop whenever the subsection contains a single enclosing rectangle. | Prior to all that, I'd get rid of the header. Maybe it's constant height, that would be easiest. If it's the same colour style, then maybe in HSV colour space. Play around a bit.

Comment: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop2/index.php

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to be getting any **OpenCV** answers, so I had a try with **ImageMagick**, just in the Terminal at the command-line. **ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows for free. The technique is pretty readily adaptable to **OpenCV** so you can port it across if it works for you.

My first step was to do a 5x5 box filter and threshold at 80% to get rid of noise an scanning artefacts and then invert (probably because I was planning on using morphology, but didn't in the end).

```
convert news.jpg -depth 16 -statistic mean 5x5 -threshold 80% -negate z.png
```

[image]

I then ran that through *"Connected Components Analysis"* and discarded all blobs with too small an area (under 2000 pixels):

```
convert news.jpg -depth 16 -statistic mean 5x5 -threshold 80% -negate  \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true                           \
   -define connected-components:area-threshold=2000                    \
   -connected-components 4 -auto-level output.png
```

**Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  110: 1254x723+59+174 686.3,536.0 901824 srgb(0,0,0)
  2328: 935x723+59+910 526.0,1271.0 676005 srgb(0,0,0)
  0: 1370x1692+0+0 685.2,712.7 399651 srgb(0,0,0)
  2329: 303x722+1007+911 1158.0,1271.5 218766 srgb(0,0,0)
  25: 1262x40+54+121 685.2,140.5 49820 srgb(255,255,255)
  109: 1265x735+54+168 708.3,535.0 20601 srgb(255,255,255)
  1: 1274x64+48+48 675.9,54.5 16825 srgb(255,255,255)
  2326: 945x733+54+905 526.0,1271.0 16660 srgb(255,255,255)  
  2327: 312x732+1003+906 1169.9,1271.5 9606 srgb(255,255,255)  <--- THIS ONE
  421: 403x15+328+342 528.6,350.1 4816 srgb(255,255,255)
  7: 141x23+614+74 685.5,85.2 2831 srgb(255,255,255)
```

The fields are labelled in the first line, but the interesting ones are the second (block geometry) and fourth field  (blob area). As you can see, there are 11 lines so it has found 11 blobs in the image. The second field, `AxB+C+D` means a rectangle `A` pixels wide by `B` pixels tall with its top-left corner `C` pixels from the left edge of the image and `D` pixels down from the top.

Let's look at the one I have marked with an arrow, which starts `2327: 312x732+1003+906` and draw a rectangle over that one:

```
convert news.jpg -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" -draw "rectangle 1003,906 1315,1638" oneArticle.png
```

[image]

If you want to crop that article out into a new image:

```
convert news.jpg -crop 312x732+1003+906 article.jpg
```

[image]

If we draw in all the other boxes , we get:

[image]

Comment: nice job. In OpenCV you can discard small blobs by finding contours based on their hierarchy. It will yield you a similar result..